# Che vuol dire "farsi forza" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Mille anni che sto qui*, di Mariolina Venezia, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Candida era l'unica a conoscere la vita intima di sua zia, i suoi sogni color di rosa, le sue fantasticherie di Capodimonte. **Si fece forza di quei sogni** senza costrutto per far sí che i suoi progetti diventassero realtà.

Questa zia di Candida è Angelica, figlia di don Francesco Falcone, e i "sogni color di rosa" menzionati nel testo sono descritti in questo passo:

> La passione dei romanzi rosa gliel'aveva trasmessa sua zia Angelica, che ne era a sua volta furiosa lettrice, e proprio per questo non riusciva a trovar marito. Nei suoi anni crepuscolari, infatti, la figlia piú bella di don Francesco Falcone, farcita com'era di smancerie, aspettava imperturbabile il momento in cui dal cielo sarebbe calato un pilota, o dal mare lontano sarebbe arrivato un nostromo, e cosí disdegnava gli onesti ma reali bifolchi che le si proponevano con sempre minor frequenza.

Inoltre, il primo brano fa riferimento al fatto che Candida cerca di trarre profitto di questi sogni di Angelica per far sì che la zia si innamori di un cieco, che istruisce per farsi passare per un aviatore che aveva perso la vista in un incidente, e così potersi anche lei sposare, come spiega questo passaggio:

> Per potersi sposare dovevano aspettare che Angelica fosse sistemata. Lo aveva preteso Oreste, che dagli abissi della sua vita sprecata emergeva ogni tanto con un atto di inutile tirannia. Le speranze di maritare Angelica erano ormai nulle, ma Candida si impegnò talmente che di matrimoni alla fine ce ne furono non uno o due, ma tre, e misero sottosopra tutto il paese.

Immagino che l'espressione "sogni senza costrutto" abbia a che vedere con il fatto che i sogni di Angelica non si erano mai avverati (non ne sono del tutto sicura, però).

Non capisco il significato di "si fece forza di quei sogni" nel primo brano. Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/forza) ho trovato che "forza" nella locuzione "fasi forza"

> si avvicina al sign. di coraggio, capacità di resistenza morale

Anche sul [De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/farsi-forza) per "farsi forza" si legge

> 1. cercare di sopportare le avversità, di avere coraggio: fatti forza, non lasciarti andare così!
> 2. indursi a fare qcs., forzarsi: per riuscire a non arrabbiarmi con lui devo proprio farmi forza

Tuttavia, non mi sembra che queste accezioni abbiano molto senso nel contesto del testo. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "si fece forza di quei sogni" nel primo brano citato?

Comment: Credo che "si fece forza" sia usato in modo non tradizionale, intendendo piuttosto che Candida decise di usare quei sogni a proprio vantaggio, avvalersene come una forza nuova - una forza in più - per raggiungere il suo scopo.